# Convert php regex to javascript exclude first 150 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't want to capture the first 150 characters and then capture everything else.

```
/(?<=\A.{150})(.*)/g
```

this is the expression I wrote in PHP but I need to do it in JavaScript and I cant work around not having lookbehind

this is javascript regex that I wrote

```
/(?:.*)(?!.{150})/g
```

Comment: Use `/^.{150}(.*)/` and grab the Group 1 contents.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just do `str.substring(151)`?

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking it.

The pattern you want is `/^.{150}(.*)/`, and then you pull out the contents of capture group 1. And, for added fun, this pattern will work equally well in just about every engine under the sun, because it uses only basic token types and quantifiers.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/csbMso/1)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need lookarounds for this

```
^.{150}(.+)
```

is all you need. https://regex101.com/r/P7keW9/1